# How to remove blank lines from HTML with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have a HTML document that contains lots of needless blank lines which I'd like to remove. Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>Testing
```

I've tried the following code but it removed every newline, I just want to remove the ones that are blank lines.

```
static string RemoveLineReturns(string html)
    {
        html = html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
        return html;
    }
```

Any idea how to do this with HTMLAgilityPack?
Thanks,
J.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647716/how-to-remove-empty-lines-from-a-formatted-string

Comment: You want to remove the blank lines or the nodes which are empty?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743344/remove-whitespaces-and-newlines-when-parsing-with-htmlagilitypack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that HTMLAgilityPack currently features a native solution for that.

For such scenarios I use the following Regex:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"( |\t|\r?\n)\1+", "$1");
```

This preserves whitespaces and line endings correctly, while condensing multiple tabs, newlines and whitespaces into one.

Comment: Worked really well, nice and simple solution. Thanks Darkseal!

Comment: I tried the same way but didn't work for me, I made below small change and worked.
 Regex.Replace(html, @"( |\t|\r|\n)+", string.Empty)

Answer (score 5):

One possible way using Html Agility Pack :

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
//TODO: load your HtmlDocument here

//select all empty (containing white-space(s) only) text nodes :
var xpath = "//text()[not(normalize-space())]";
var emptyNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

//replace each and all empty text nodes with single new-line text node
foreach (HtmlNode emptyNode in emptyNodes)
{
    emptyNode.ParentNode
             .ReplaceChild(HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(Environment.NewLine) 
                            , emptyNode
                           );
}
```

Comment: For use with a SQL query, I found that I had to use an empty string "" instead of Environment.NewLine: emptyNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(""), emptyNode);