# parse rel canonical with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How can i parse the rel="canonical" tag with URL from a html document?

I want to find the url here:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593147/html-agility-pack-make-code-look-neat" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `doc` is your `HtmlDocument` object.

```
HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel]");
```

should get you the `link` elements that have a `rel` attribute. Now iterate:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
{
    string url;
    if (link.Attributes["rel"] == "canonical") {
        url = link.Attributes["href"];
    }
}
```

Also, it's possible to filter links in the SelectNodes call to only get the ones with "canonical": `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel='canonical']");`

Not tested code, but you get the idea :)

Comment: Wouldn't  `//link[@rel='canonical']` be easier?

Comment: I was about to say that, yes :)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is no longer correct, updated code is below:

```
var links = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel]");

string canonical;

foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
{
    if (link.Attributes["rel"].Value == "canonical")
    {
        canonical = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the accepted answer? It appears to still work? Possibly an issue with single vs double quotes maybe?

Comment: @MossPalmer This was a couple of months ago, but IIRC you need the **.Value** now

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for clearing that up. I had added that without even looking. Might be worth noting that in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I had thought the //link[@rel]='canonical' was the part that you were flagging as wrong but this still works well.

Comment: How about  canonical = link.GetAttributeValue("href", null); instead of canonical = link.Attributes["href"].Value;  This will throw exception if the link attribute is null

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(_html);

String link = (from x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
           where x.Name == "link"
           && x.Attributes["rel"] != null
           && x.Attributes["rel"].Value == "canonical"
           && x.Attributes["href"] != null
           select x.Attributes["href"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlDocument html= new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(_html);

var _canonical = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[@rel='canonical']").Attributes["href"].Value;

Comment: It was a solution to the question above

Comment: Oh I see, in that case please add an explanation of the code. How does it work? Why does it help?