# How to read HTML template, replace text and convert back to HTML

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

I am currently loading a html file from a filepath and reading it as text. I then replace certain characters in the file itself and I want to convert it back to html.

This is how I do it currently:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load(@message.Location);
content = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

//Code to replace text

var eContent = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(content);
```

When I debug and check what eContent holds, I can see newline characters like "\r\n". If I copy and paste the text into a .html file, only the text appears, not a proper html page.

I'm using Html AgilityPack already and am unsure of what else I need to do.

EDIT:

I have also tried

```
var result = new HtmlString(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack is great to read and modify Html files you cannot create readable output.

[Try with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31493237/11763335)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using...

```
 string savePath = "path to save html file, ie C://myfile.html";

 string textRead = File.ReadAllText(@"Path of original html file");
  //replace or manipulate as needed... ie textRead = textRead.Replace("", "");
 File.WriteAllText(savePath, textRead);
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to write it to a file. I need the string to send via another function.

Comment: then remove the File.WriteAllText and pass the string textRead where ever you want to, it will keep all its tags and HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which inherits [ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Just remember to set `ContentType` to `text/html`.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FileToTextToHtml()
    {
        string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\\HtmlTest.html");

        var result= new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = fileContents,
            ContentType = "text/html",
        };
        return result;
    }
```