# Email database report in html table format

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

I need to generate a report from our production sql server database and daily email the report as an html table to some users.I have made the procedure, but not sure how i should feed the data to an html table and email it.

I have done same kind of thing before,but using a very tedious method.I created an Html template file, which had an html table.Suppose user wanted age info, I kept it as [Age] in the template.Then extracted the age data from database and replaced it with [Age] in my C# code. I also had to replace all inline CSS. Very tedious.

But now i have a lot of data to send and by following above method it will be even more tedious.Can anyone please suggest any method to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating email message using the template. I suggest, you can use Html Agility Pack for this. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490765/which-is-the-best-html-tidy-pack-is-there-any-option-in-html-agility-pack-to-ma) for your reference.

You can also check its [documentation](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) on how can you use it.

Goodluck!