# how to get data from web page using c#

Tags: c#

I need ask if any code can search for text or data in a Web page and displays the next word in the program.  This is discussed a lot in the internet but I can not find a way, can I see an example?

Comment: I voted to close but here is a hint:  search google for `web spider c#` or `web crawler c#`

Comment: Your question is too broad and isn't very clear. Please check out how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

A vague question is going to get you a vague answer, but you could potentially look at using the web agility pack to scrape data from a webpage via LINQ to Objects.

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

[What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

[Parsing or Extracting the content of html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408270/parsing-or-extracting-the-content-of-html-table)

Comment: htmlagilitypack is probably exactly what he wants.